# How do I select distinct IDs from JSON datatype in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm using MySQL 5.7 with JSON data type.
This is my attributes column from two different rows:

```
{
"7": "Volvo", 
"57": "Opel", 
"65": "Tesla", 
"66": "Ford" 
}

{
"7": "Volvo",
"67": "Skoda", 
"68": "Audi", 
"69": "BMW"
}
```

I have several thousands of rows with all different IDs/Cars.
I want to get all distinct IDs.

What's the best way to do this when it comes down to performance?
Is there a way to use a SELECT query or is it better to do this in an array in PHP, which is the fastest way?

Comment: You can use `array_unique`. You just need to convert your json object into php array.

Comment: Thanks Salim, this works really great!